# Windows Server 2016 unable to ping or pinged from another server

Tags: windows, windows-server-2016, ping

I am  wondering why my newly created server is unable to be pinged from another server or to PING another server?

What I have done so far:
- I have allowed the file and sharing firewall protocol
- turned off the firewall

I managed to ping the new server from another client/devices, however,  only server to server seems doesn't work

I'm able to ping the gateway though, and RDP into the new server

If.anyone has similar experiences please kindly share

Comment: Hello Tom and welcome, It might belong to the Access Control List (ACL) on your switch to prevent ping from a specific port to another specific port. Please check it in the switch config.

Comment: Hi Tom, i think thats not relevant due to there are another 2 server that coming from the same switch, however i think i need to check the ACL because the new server is actually connected through VPN, and yet the other devices / client able to access the server... only the server to server connection thats being the problem

Comment: Thank you @ Dave M for the grammar correction, sorry for spelling mistakes

Comment: The problem is within mikrotik subnet routes setting that doesnt allow VPN node to communicate directly into the server subnets

Comment: The answer is subnet mask in VPM